# Google Sheet / Excel Formula for identifying consecutive review ratings based on different dates

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of reviews (~2000) and I'm trying to identify consecutive reviews by the same person.  For example, I want to identify when someone has given some number of consecutive reviews of the same rating, namely, five 5-star reviews in a row.

There are other columns in the sheet linked below, but I've omitted them to cleanse the data.

[Google Sheets Example Review Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yx1rEGlCdgrWks_TKSSCzyQqbgu182LHvUlS75CzZyM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to sort by Reviewer then Date. Add another column called "Consecutive 5's". Then your formula in the first cell is this:

```
=IF(C2<>5,0,IF(AND(D2=D1,C2=C1,C2=5),E1+1,1))
```

Here column C is Rating and column D is Reviewer).

You'll see a 0 if the rating is not a 5. If the rating is a 5, it will continue to count ratings by that user until the 5-streak ends. You can then conditional format those cells where the value meets your limit.

This is Excel, but would be surprised if google sheets cannot support this formula.

[image]

Comment: Amazing, Thank you!